# Neptune fails to bulk load (connection time-out)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-neptune

I am trying to bulk load on Neptune db through Neptune notebooks. I initially tried %load but after entering all the information it fails after 5sec.

Then I tried using Curl and Request.post.

I even simply tried to just perform a requests.get(endpoint) where
https://your-neptune-endpoint:port/loader

The default port is 8182 but I noticed that my cluster has a 7999 so I’ve been using that one.

There is a magic command I run in notebook and I get port=7999 and port_proxy=8182.

Everything points to that I am unable to connect because there should be an Inbound rule in my security group but I already have that.

Not sure what else to do. Is there a way I can test every access and inbound rule if working as expected ?

Comment: The port_proxy functionality in the notebooks is only ever needed if you launch the notebook from your local machine. Are you connecting from a Notebook Instance attached to your VPC or one running locally using your own Jupyter Server install?

Comment: Also, can you validate what port was configured for your Neptune cluster?  If you login to the AWS console and go to the Neptune console, you can click on your cluster and choose the Connectivity & Security tab.  The port is shown on the right-most column after your cluster endpoints.

Comment: The port is 7999